# Find the differential of this function

Tags: calculus, differential

Given a bounded open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2=\{x={(x_1,x_2):x_i\in \mathbb{R}}\}$  and a function $F: V \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$F(u) = \int_{\Omega}{K(u)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v \,dx},\qquad\forall v\in V$$

where $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$

Here, we can consider that $v$ is given and K(u) is a nonlinear function, for example, $K(u)=u^2$.

What is the differential $DF(u)\delta u$ of $F$ at $u$?

Comment: Is $K$ gaussian curvature, or just a random differentiable function? and is  the integral with respect to $u$?

Comment: I have just edited my question above.

Comment: the $v$ doesn't really make sense as you have defined it as a set rather than a function, but can we assume $v\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$?

Comment: Also what are the properties of $u$? you have put $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, but it need to be defined on a function space containing $u$.

Comment: yes, I'm wrong. I have just edited again. I'm sorry because I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Could you remind me what $H_0^1(\Omega ) $ is?

Comment: $H^1_0(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega): \nabla u\in L^2(\Omega) \text{ and } u=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear this up, I would like to mention that the reason this all got confused is because F is a FUNCTIONAL  rather than a function.

$$ F'(u)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {F(u+hf)-F(u)}{h}$$

Now: $$\frac {F(u+hf)-F(u)}{h}=\int\frac {K(u+hf)\nabla (u+fh)\cdot\nabla v-K(u)\nabla (u)\cdot\nabla v}{h}dx=\int\frac {(K(u+fh)\nabla (u)-K(u)\nabla (u))\cdot\nabla v+hK(u+hf)\nabla (f)\cdot\nabla v}{h}dx$$

Taking the limit we get:

$=\int K'(u)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+K(u)\nabla f\cdot\nabla v dx$

Thus $F'(u)=\int K'(u)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+K(u)\nabla f\cdot\nabla v dx$ where $f\in V $

Now the DIFFERENTIAL is actually the first variation of F where $hf=\delta u $

So the differential is:

$\int K'(u)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+K(u)\nabla \delta u\cdot\nabla(v)dx $

Comment: Can you show me why we can ignore the integral sign here?

PS. You forget $\nabla(f)\cdot \nabla v$ at the last term in your above transformation.

Comment: That's the derivative of $F$ at $u$, how about the differential? Is that $DF(u,f)=F'(u)f$?

Comment: I missed out the integral because I didn't want to typeset it, I can't see the term I missed out?

Comment: Sorry what's a differential, I thought you meant derivative?

Comment: I think it would be $F'(u)\delta u$

Comment: The differential of a function $f$ is $Df(x,\Delta x)$ in the following description: If $f$ satisfies: $f(x+\Delta x)= F(x) + Df(x,\Delta x)\Delta x + \varepsilon$ where the error $\varepsilon$ in the approximation satisfies $\varepsilon/\Delta x \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$

Comment: You can see more at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function)

Comment: Taking into account what you have said I have edited my answer and I believe it to be correct now :)

Comment: Oh, I think you are wrong now. $hf$ is better than $hu$. If I'm not mistaken, you have used here the [Gateau derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative), haven't you? I'm better agreed with your previous result than this one.

Comment: But it needs to be in the direction of $u$, hence the $hu$ if we did $hf$ it would be the $f$ derivative evaluated at $u$

Comment: So, come back to the main question about differential. We need the increment $\Delta u$ in term $F(u+\Delta u)$. If you use here $hu$, the increment term is that $\Delta u=hu$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is indeed, hope I helped!

Comment: One more problem. Here we see that differential of F is a linear function of the increment $\delta u$. However, this linear function is not always in the form of $F'(u).\delta u$ (with $F'(u)$ doesn't contain $\delta u$).It can be a function of 2 variables $u, \delta u$. For example, you can see in this [link](http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/lehyaric/ffcs/doc/ff/ffdocse15.html). If we do as your method, we always get the former form.That's the reason why I'm afraid of the second term in your last result. Your idea about it?

Comment: Perhaps the final term should be $\frac{ K (u)\nabla (\delta u)\cdot\nabla v}{\delta u}$

Comment: Could you show me more about "Now the DIFFERENTIAL is actually the first variation of $F$ where $hf=\delta u$". What is "first variation of $F$?

Comment: After reading [one document](http://www.vgu.edu.vn/fileadmin/pictures/studies/master/compeng/study_subjects/modules/math/notes/chapter-05.pdf) about Gâteaux differential, I see that your work is right. The Gâteaux differential $DF(u)(h)$ of a functional/function $F$ at $u\in V$ in direction of $h\in V$ is $DF(u)(h)=\lim_{t\to 0}{\dfrac{F(u+th)-F(u)}{t}}=\dfrac{d}{dt}F(u+th)|_{t=0}$. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help