# How to find the Frechet differential of a functional?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

We know that the Fréchet differential $DF(u,\delta)$ of a functional $F:V\to V$ is satisfied (cf. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative))
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0}{\dfrac{\left\|F(u+\delta)-F(u)-DF(u,\delta)\right\|_V}{\left\|\delta\right\|}}=0 \qquad (1)
$$
where $V$ is a functional space, for example, $V=H_0^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega = \{x=(x_1,x_2):x_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Or we have the alternative definition (cf. [EncyclopediaOfMath](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fr%C3%A9chet_differential)):
$$F(u+\delta)=F(u)+DF(u,\delta)+o(\delta)$$
where $\lim_{\left\|\delta\right\|\to 0}{\dfrac{\left\|o(\delta)\right\|}{\left\|\delta\right\|}}=0$.

**The question** is how to calculate the Fréchet differential of a given function/functional? If we only need to check whether some $DF(u,\delta)$ is Frechet differential of $F$ or not, that is easier because we only need to check (1) but in this case, I need to find the differential.

**For example**, find the Fréchet differential of $F$ given by
$$F(u)=\int_{\Omega}{K(u)\nabla u\cdot\nabla v}, \qquad \forall v\in V$$
where $K(u)$ which is a nonlinear functional w.r.t $u$ has some neccessary conditions. If we use Gâteaux differential (cf. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative)), we will get the result:
$$DF(u,\delta)=\int_{\Omega}{K'(u)\delta\nabla u\cdot\nabla v}+\int_{\Omega}{K(u)\nabla\delta\cdot\nabla v}$$

Comment: Should there be a $\delta $ in the second to last integral?

Comment: As your [previous work](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751900/find-the-differential-of-this-function/752028?noredirect=1#comment1565982_752028), I think there is no $\delta$, right?

Comment: Correct, I believe there should be no $\delta$

Comment: You mean the SECOND term? If that, what I have written is correct?

Comment: I mean in the first integral of DF

Comment: $K'(u)\delta$ is the action of $K'(u)$ on $\delta$. It looks correct to me.

Comment: @ellya: I forget to tell you, because you calculate the directional derivative w.r.t $\delta$, so we will get $K'(u)\delta$ instead of $K'(u)$. Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 0):

You just write down $F(u+\delta)$ and subtract $F(u)$. Then you cross your fingers and hope to isolate a term that is *linear* in $\delta$. Finally, you try to prove that this linear term is the differential of $F$. And do not forget that there *rules* of differentiation, similar to those you learn in a calculus course.

Of course, you may also try to compute the Gateaux derivative, and then prove its continuity.

Comment: If we do the Gateaux first and know in beforehand the differential, that's nothing to say. But in this case, after calculating $F(u+\delta)-F(u)$, what I get is not always easy to guess the differential, especially in above example.

Comment: Nobody says that differential calculus in infinite-dimensional spaces is easy. However, the Fréchet derivative is the perfect analog of the differential in $\mathbb{R}^n$, while the Gateaux derivative corresponds to the directional derivative. The main difference is that you no longer have a *finite* set of directional derivatives that form a basis. Anyway, $K(u)\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$ is a product, so you should *guess* what its derivative is.

Comment: great, very useful, I will try to guess and find out the rule :)